# Deploy website to IIS from VS - options aren't present?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2019, webdeploy

I am trying to get web deployment working, but following [Microsoft: Publish to IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-iis?view=vs-2019#install-and-configure-web-deploy-on-windows-server)

Prerequisites:

- Must have VS2019 [yes]
- Server is running Windows 2019 DataCenter
- Running IIS 10
- ASP 2.0, 3.0 and 4.7 installed
- Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Server installed
- Web Account Manager Service running
- Web Deployment Agent Service running
- Web Management Service Running
- IIS Management Scripts and Tools installed

With the above installed, the instruction say to restart the IIS Console and chose **Deploy > Configure Web Deploy Publishing** from the Default website, but it's not showing (on the Default Site, or my App Services site)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the close iis manager if it is open.

Go to the "programs and feature".

Select web deploy -> click change.

Enable IIS Manager UI Module, IIS Deployment Handler, and Remote Agent Service.

[image]

Click next -> change -> finish.